# Filter Object Array - Power Automate

Tags: flow, power-automate, microsoft-flow, ms-flow

I'm working on Power Automate to add users in O365 group. When I'm trying to add if user already exists as "user exists already" so to prevent adding further just checking if user is already part of the group.

When trying filter it always shows as false.

Group JSON data

```
[
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "businessPhones": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "displayName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "givenName": {},
        "jobTitle": {},
        "mail": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "mobilePhone": {},
        "officeLocation": {},
        "preferredLanguage": {},
        "surname": {},
        "userPrincipalName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
]
```

I'm checking against multiple selection person column, so having for each and inside filter array.

[image]

Comment: just an idea: it might be a case sensitivity issue. It might that the userPricipalName does not match the casing of the Email field.

Comment: even I thought the same, but it's not